# Parsing elements in second nesting level of XML file

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I am working on a little executable application. The application is simply an XML Parser that will parse an XML file and store the data parsed into a database. So the XML file that this application will do its magic on has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<events>
    <event>
        <book>Felicity Fly</book>
        <author>Christina Gabbitas</author>
        <bookImgUrl>http://www.whsmith.co.uk/Images/Products\957\255\9780957255203_t_f.jpg</bookImgUrl>
        <info>Christina Gabbitas will be signing copies of her new book, Felicity Fly. Books should be bought from WHSmith. Proof of purchase may be necessary</info>
        <date>25 May 2013</date>
        <startTime>10:30</startTime>
        <location>
            <name>WHSmith Brent Cross</name>
            <address>Brent Cross Shopping Centre</address>
            <city>London</city>
            <county/>
            <postcode>NW4 3FB</postcode>
            <tel>020 8202 4226</tel>
        </location>
    </event>
    <!-- many more events as above here -->
</events>
```

And here is what I have so far in terms of code parsing logic.

```
namespace XMLParser
{
    public class Parser
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path_to_xml = "data.xml";
            var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
            var events = from e in xdoc.Descendants("event")
                         select new {
                             Book = (string)e.Element("book").Value,
                             Author = (string)e.Element("author").Value,
                             BookImgUrl = (string)e.Element("bookImgUrl").Value,
                             Info = (string)e.Element("info").Value,
                             Date = (string)e.Element("date").Value,
                             Time = (string)e.Element("startTime").Value,
                             // stuck here
                         }
        }
    }
}
```

I get stuck where I get to the Location node, I don't know how to parse the location related information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide whether you're using `(string)XElement` casting or `XElement.Value` property.

`(string)e.Element("book").Value` compiles and works fine, but `XElement.Value` is already a string, so casting it to string is pointless. I suggest using `(string)XElement`, because it won't cause `NullReferenceException` when Element won't be find.

You can also use `let` keyword to get `e.Element("location")` only once, and then use it to get all `Location`-related values:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var events = from e in xdoc.Descendants("event")
             let l = e.Element("location")
             select new {
                 Book = (string)e.Element("book"),
                 Author = (string)e.Element("author"),
                 BookImgUrl = (string)e.Element("bookImgUrl"),
                 Info = (string)e.Element("info"),
                 Date = (string)e.Element("date"),
                 Time = (string)e.Element("startTime"),
                 Location = new {
                     Name = (string)l.Element("name"),
                     Address = (string)l.Element("address"),
                     City = (string)l.Element("city"),
                     County = (string)l.Element("county"),
                     Postcode = (string)l.Element("postcode"),
                     Tel = (string)l.Element("tel")
                 }
             };

Console.WriteLine(events.First().Location.City);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to keep the location fields nested...

```
       var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
       var events = from e in xdoc.Descendants("event")
                     select new {
                         Book = e.Element("book").Value,
                         Author = e.Element("author").Value,
                         BookImgUrl = e.Element("bookImgUrl").Value,
                         Info = e.Element("info").Value,
                         Date = e.Element("date").Value,
                         Time = e.Element("startTime").Value,
                         Location = new {
                             Name = e.Element("location").Element("name").Value,
                             Address = e.Element("location").Element("address").Value,
                             City = e.Element("location").Element("city").Value,
                             County = e.Element("location").Element("county").Value,
                             Postcode = e.Element("location").Element("postcode").Value,
                             Tel = e.Element("location").Element("tel").Value
                         }
                     };

            Console.WriteLine(events.First().Location.City);
```

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Thanks; I copied it from the question. Fixed.